# dhtmlx scheduler time field gets blank when odd time gets loaded from database

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I have configured the time step for the time section of the light box as 15.

Below is the code:

```
scheduler.config.time_step = 15;
```

This enables the time combo boxes to be populated with 15 minutes interval like - 12:00,12:15,12:30,12:45, etc.

Now, when I load the event from the database with Start time as 01:09 am and End time as 01:39 am, the corresponding fields are filled as empty. These fields are only filled when the Start/End time is a multiple of 15.

How should I resolve this issue?

Is there a way to make these combo boxes editable?

[image: I have also attached a screenshot to understand the problem.]